# What is the difference between angular data table dtInstance.reloadData() vs dtInstance.rerender()

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular data table to load a list of data which is returned from a service call. It has server-side pagination enabled with the option to toggle pagination length using rowCount variable

```
var vm=this;
vm.DisplaySLAChart  =true;           
var rowCount = (vm.DisplaySLAChart==true?5:10);
vm.dtInstance = {};    

vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
.withFnServerData(serverData)
.withDataProp('data')
.withOption('processing', true)
.withOption('serverSide', true)
.withOption('paging', true)
.withPaginationType('full_numbers')
.withDisplayLength(rowCount)
.withDOM('<"top">t<ip"bottom"><"clear">');

function serverData(sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings)
{
     //Server side data fetching logic
}
```

I have a requirement to change this page length based upon a "`vm.DisplaySLAChart`" flag set by the user on a checkbox ng-change event. Checkbox is setting up the value for "`vm.DisplaySLAChart`" using ng-model.
If the flag is true then show only 5 records per page. else display 10 records per page.

check box `ng-change` calls the following method.

```
vm.toggleLength = function () {

 var rowCnt = (vm.DisplaySLAChart == true ? 5 : 10);
 vm.dtOptions.withDisplayLength(rowCnt);
 vm.dtInstance.reloadData();
};
```

Here if I use `vm.dtInstance.reloadData()` then the data table loads the data with the number records as specified in `rowcnt` variable. No problem at all.

If I use `vm.dtInstance.rerender();` instead of `vm.dtInstance.reloadData();` then number of records displayed is wrong sometimes.

I would like to know what is the difference between rerender and reloaddata.
Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

dtInstance.rerender() : This will redraw table completely. This does not necessary resend the data to server.

dtInstance.reloadData() : Reload the data of the DataTable by resending the request to the server. This API is only available for the Ajax Renderer and Promise Renderer.